# JavaFx - fx:id not changed after creating scene second time

Tags: java, javafx

Everything works fine after switching to scene with my method (swichScene) at the first time.
But if I go to another scene and switch back (second time opening scene) the Buttons in my GameController aren't reassigned, so I have the old Buttons and can't change anything.
The variables get updated when pressing the Button.

Steps to recreate:

1. create 2 fxml scenes with at least 2 buttons in the second
2. switch to second scene and change the Image in the button which isn't pressed (When the other one is pressed)
   -> works
3. Switch back to scene 1 and repeat step 2
   -> doesn't work

My Controller:

```
public class GameController {
... some stuff ...
    @FXML
    private Button gameField0;
... some stuff...
```

My Button in game.fxml which has GameController as controller

```
<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="1000.0" style="-fx-background-color: #0E328C;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/19" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
fx:controller="com.example.tictactoe.GameController">
... some stuff ...
                        <Button fx:id="gameField0" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#pressedField0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="100.0" styleClass="tttfield">
                           <graphic>
                              <ImageView fitHeight="75.0" fitWidth="75.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
                           </graphic>
                        </Button>
... some stuff ...
```

My start():

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(App.class.getResource("startpage.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load());
    // Stage setup
    stage.setTitle("TicTacToe");
    Image icon = new Image(App.class.getResource("icon.png").toString());
    stage.getIcons().add(icon);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
    this.stage = stage;
    this.scene = scene;
}
```

Switching to game.fxml which has GameController as controller

```
public static void swichScene(Scene currentScene, Stage stage) throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(App.class.getResource(game.fxml));
    currentScene.setRoot(fxmlLoader.load());
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

Comment: All you are doing is setting the root of the current scene.  You aren't creating a new scene so of course the state of the scene hasn't changed.

Comment: Always try to supply a [mcve] for debugging issues, so your problem can be easily replicated.